# How do I ignore changes to an attribute in Terraform that isn't configurable?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

AWS RDS instances have an attribute called `latest_restorable_time` that gets updated continuously by AWS. This attribute isn't configurable, it's a read-only value.

My Terraform plan output always shows that my RDS instance objects have changed outside of Terraform because this attribute changes. I'd like to ignore this attribute to get rid of the noise from my plan outputs.

Adding an `ignore_changes` block to my RDS configuration doesn't work because the attribute isn't configurable.

Here is the plan output:

```
Terraform detected the following changes made outside of Terraform since the
last "terraform apply":
  # module.app_db.aws_db_instance.app_database has changed
  ~ resource "aws_db_instance" "app_database" {
        id                                    = "app-stag"
      ~ latest_restorable_time                = "2023-04-12T16:25:00Z" -> "2023-04-12T17:25:00Z"
        tags                                  = {}
        # (50 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }
```

Edit: For clarification, I'd like to know if it's possible to ignore changes to resource attributes that aren't configurable parameters. The one I'm currently having a problem with is an example of an attribute that isn't set through the configuration, but that gets updated continuously by the provider.

Comment: I imagine you received a downvote because you haven't shared your terraform config or the actual output of your terraform plan. With that said, the `aws_db_instance` resource does have a `restore_to_point_in_time` block with a `restore_time` & `use_latest_restorable_time` attribute. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/db_instance

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I was wondering about the downvote. There's no relevant configuration to show, the parameter `latest_restorable_time` isn't a configurable parameter. The plan output isn't super interesting but I'll add it. I was trying to keep this question general though, I want to know how, as a rule, to ignore resource attribute that aren't part of the configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this was caused by a bug in Terraform that was fixed in version 1.2. Prior to version 1.2, Terraform plan was showing all resource drift in the managed resources. Starting in v1.2, "only external changes which may have contributed to changes in the plan will be shown".

[Relevant issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/28803)

My Gitlab Terraform integration was using Terraform v1.1, which is why I was still having this issue. I changed my gitlab-ci.yml file to use a Terraform v1.3 image and it fixed the issue; my pipelines no longer show resource drift due to that `latest_restorable_time` attribute.